# customize Highcharts tooltip on marker points and show default tooltip on the other points

Tags: highcharts, tooltip

I have a Highcharts line chart going and I have tooltip enabled.
How can i customize the tooltip only for points with marker and have all the other points show the default tooltip. I need to add extra text in the tooltip for points that have markers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out how to do that:

```
tooltip :{
    formatter: function(a) {
        if(condition)
            return "custom tooltip for the marker point";

        //otherwise call the defaultFormatter function this way
        return a.defaultFormatter.call(this, a);
    }
}
```